# Low beams don't work but high beams do. What do I do?

Tags: electrical

It's a Chevy HHR 2006 and I don't know what to do. First one low beam went out now both are not working but both high beams are working. What do I do?

Comment: What have you checked - have you checked the bulbs? Most likely scenario is they are blown. It happens. If they are fine you need to look at wiring and switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have an auto lamp switch? If so you could have a faulty light sensor or switch try manually turning them on

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely blown bulbs. Each bulb has 2 filaments in it, one for low beams and one for high beams.

Since the low beams failed at separate times and the high beams are still working, it is less likely you have an electrical fault, and more likely the bulbs failed because they were from the same production line, same usage stats, etc.

You local auto parts store should have an applications guide to tell you which bulbs are the correct type for your application.

Comment: I believe it's not a bulb problem because when I start the car with my remote the lights come on. Both of them were lit up and they were not the high beams either. I'll try checking the electric flow but I may just have to take her in and get a check up. Thank you

Comment: I will try it. I went and baught new bulbs just incase. I can put them in myself too. I don't know why they come on when I start the car but you may be right so I went a got new ones. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is for old Chevy Trucks (1972 Blazer in this instance).  On the back of the
fuze box, on the other side of the firewall (under the hood)  is the pass-thru of the wiring harness.  If this is loose, then the contacts may open and the circuits
of headlight control are inop.